# When I open my website, I do not have a domain but when the domain name comes in when I open the page in the website, how to delete it

Tags: wordpress

http://redkingfashionhub.com/

http://maxithelp.com/redkingfashionhub/products/

When I open my website, I do not have a domain but when the domain name comes in when I open the page in the website, how to delete it

Answer (score 0):

I think at first you made a demo site on server where "maxithelp.com" is hosted.
Later you just moved the whole site to new server where "redkingfashionhub.com" is being hosted.
That's why whenever you click on any link it's address back to the previous addresses.

Solution:
Just replace all the occurrence of "http://maxithelp.com/redkingfashionhub/" from your new database to "http://redkingfashionhub.com/".
It will short your problem.